# Aspect ratio of image loaded using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I load image using `UIImagePickerController` to my `UIImageView`. The problem is I don't know how to keep the aspect ratio of `UIImageView` so the loaded image is no distortion. If I fixed one aspect ration, it is good for iPhone 6, but the ratio is not correct for iPhone 4. How to get the correct aspect ration it works for iPhone 4,5,6 and iPad.

Comment: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/auto-layout-in-ios-6-keep-aspect-ratio-of-image

Comment: What content mode is the UIImageView? I'd try Aspect Fit.

Comment: Do you use storyboard or xib and auto layout or auto resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `contentMode` of the `UIImageView` to either `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`. Read more about contentMode [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode).

Answer (score 1):

using swift

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

using objective-c

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```